# How would you explain this case?

Tags: graph-theory

> In a di-graph, when each strongly connected component is reduced to a single node, then the resulting di-graph is a directed acyclic digraph.

I understand that the difference between a di-graph and a directed acyclic digraph is that a directed acyclic digraph has no cycle present. But not sure how to fully explain the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had a cycle after the identification, then all the points in the cycle would have been in the same strongly connected component and would have been collapsed instead into a single vertex.

To show this take two points $a,b$ in the cycle. Denote by the same name the strongly connected components that they represent from the original graph. Since $a,b$ are part of a cycle, you can connect them ($a$ to $b$ and there is also one for going from $b$ to $a$) by a path $a\to x_1\to x_2\to ...\to x_n\to b$. Now take representatives (vertexes from the original graph belonging to the strongly connected component) for each $a,x_1,...,x_n,b$. Lets denote them by the same names with primes $a',x_1',...,x_n',b$. Since there is a directed edge from $a$ to $x_1$, then there is some $a''\in a$ and $x_1''\in x_1$ such that $a''\to x_1''$ is an edge of the original graph. Since $a,x_1$ are strongly connected, there is a path that connects $a'$ to $a''$ and $x_1''$ to $x_1'$. Therefore there is a path from $a'$ to $x_1'$, in the original graph. Apply the same argument to get from $x_i'$ to $x_{i+1}'$ and from $x_n'$ to $b'$.

Therefore there is a path to get from $a'$ to $b'$. Replacing their roles, there is a path to get from $b'$ to $a'$. Therefore $a'$ and $b'$ are in the same strongly connected component of the original graph.